# Perl getoptions(): empty string appears as first argument

Tags: perl

I have a perl script with usage `script -p "first argument" "second argument" ... "nth arg"`

```
GetOptions("p=s"   => \@CHOSEN_PKGS)
```

For some reason when I loop through the array @CHOSEN_PKGS, the first value is an empty string, or some uninitialized variable.

```
 if(@CHOSEN_PKGS) {
      foreach my $PKG(@CHOSEN_PKGS) {
          print "Pkg: $PKG";
 }}
```

prints...

```
Pkg: 
Pkg: <first argument>
Pkg: <second argument>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting `@CHOSEN_PKGS` before your call to `GetOptions`?  If so, then you could have a blank first element:

```
@CHOSEN_PKGS = ' ';
```

I can't reproduce your results.  When I use this code:

```
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions("p=s" => \@CHOSEN_PKGS);
if (@CHOSEN_PKGS) {
    foreach my $PKG (@CHOSEN_PKGS) {
        print "Pkg: $PKG";
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Here is what I get:

```
script -p "first argument" "second argument" "nth arg"
Pkg: first argument
```

If I use `-p` 3 times, I get:

```
script -p "first argument" -p "second argument" -p "nth arg"
Pkg: first argument
Pkg: second argument
Pkg: nth arg
```

See also: [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)